# Include wordpress header file out of wordpress

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to wordpress , I want to include wordpress header file into my PHP file so that I can show the same header as the the wordpress site.I was wondering if there is a way I could do this.I need to build an application that requires PHP to do this.

Comment: You need to add this bit first, `require("../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php"); ?>` - but even then it's not going to work properly, as the wordpress header file already includes the `<head>` tag, so you'll get duplicate tags etc.

Comment: @NickR does wp-blog-header.php work independently without the core of wp?

Comment: No, it makes a call to `wp-load.php`

Comment: @NickR so you comment does not make alot of sense =] If OP tried, it would not result in dublicate head tags, but missing functions in the backend. Making OP more confused..

Comment: If you directly include `header.php`, then nothing shows up on the screen, but if you view source, you can see the errors : things such as, `Fatal error: Call to undefined function language_attributes()` etc. OP - can you view the source of the page, and see if the errors show up there..

Comment: WP is wrong framework(well, it's a primarily CMS) to use partially. Don't include anything from WP, you can work FROM WP and include your own libraries, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not include/require files straight out of wordpress template into a php files. 
The header.php might use lots of functions unknown to you current code.

Just take a look inside the file.

If you are trying to make a wordpress template you should read the wordpress codex which has lots of details on that subject.

Remember to enable php warnings and errors. Also logs are usefull.

Comment: @Waqas could you explain exactly what you are trying to do? Extracting a theme from wordpress into your own site, or make a theme for wordpress?

Comment: actually i am making my own a simple application out of wordpress but i want to include ony header and footer and sidebar without having posts in it and my program runs in the content area so my theme will be also displayed and the user will also check my program

Comment: @Waqas building anything with wordpress being a dependency is a bad bad thing to do. Either build something that in no way use wordpress or build it into wordpress as a theme, plugin or etc. On the note of what I was saying before: Imaging the header.php used a method, defined in functions.php of the theme. Then without including the functions.php it would not work... Now functions.php itself relies on some other files (like parts of the core of wp).

Comment: Well the theme is build upon wordpress, so the best way you could go to make a modified edition would be a child theme. Search "child theme wordpress".

Comment: Did child theme not fit your needs?

Comment: Why not? Please read my previous comments and make sure you understand that wordpress is the core for the templates, meaning you need to run wordpress to load the templates.

Comment: i got it.What i can do is to make my own template like my wordpress template so thankyou for answering

Answer (score -1):

Your html is expecting the .css file to be in the same folder (ftm).
If it is so, then the .css needs

```
url(../img/bg.jpg)
```

in order to see the background image.

Comment: It would not expect to have the rest of wordpress?